# Программный поворот экрана на 180 и 270 градусов.

Tags: android

C помощью setRequestedOrientation можно задать ориентацию SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE
или SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT или привязать её к G-сенсору. В последнем случае видно, что система поддерживает ещё две ориентации экрана, т.е. переворот на 180 относительно упомянутых вариантов. Вопрос как можно в программе установить эти ориентации.

Comment: Надо повернуть вьюху: [getRotation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Display.html#getRotation).

Comment: Однако это get, а не set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE,  SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_PORTRAIT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/ActivityInfo.html#SCREEN_ORIENTATION_REVERSE_LANDSCAPE)

API level 9 - вот почему эклипс не предлагал такие варианты